# Why "join" in nestjs/crud not working with @ManyToOne relation?

Tags: nestjs, crud

I have two models with OneToMany relation. One client can have several rooms:

```
@Entity()
export class Room {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    client_id: number;

    @JoinColumn({ name: 'client_id' })
    @ManyToOne(() => Client, client => client.rooms)
    client: Client;

    // ...

}

@Entity()
export class Client {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(() => Room, room => room.client, { cascade: true })
    rooms: Room[];

    // ...

}
```

Also I did CRUD services and controllers like in documentation. Via curl I have posted data in those tables, here is all right. But when I try query room data with joined client - there are no client information in response:

```
 http://localhost:3000/room?limit=1&cache=0&join=client||name,description
```

this query return only data from room table without client information

```
 [{"id":1,"client_id":1,"name":"name 167","room":"room 164","price":447}]
```

What I did wrong, and how resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know anything about **query** of @Crud for controller.

```
@Crud({
  model: { type: Room },
  query: { // this resolved my issue
    join: {
      client: {
        eager: true,
        //exclude: ['password']
      }
    }
  }
})
@Controller('room')
export class RoomController {
  constructor(public service: RoomService) {}
}
```

Now all right. I hope this info will help someone